# How to scale down a responsive website?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

This might be an odd question, considering our website is fully responsive and shouldn't need to be scaled down.

Although, the client consider that since his main website is stuck on a 980px max-width, his other websites should be too.

In short, want should I do to scale down the website if the screen is bigger than 980px right to that resolution ?

To add further details, we used media-queries to make the website responsive on mobile, tablet and desktop. The thing is that 980px falls in the tablet res, and the client wants it in desktop res.

Comment: a wrapper iframe  that opens a website inside?

Comment: The full details would be the entire source code.
Maybe I should have posted in another SE site, but I don't know of one which would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to nigotiate with the client but you can add a div with the class `wrapper` or `content` wrap all the page content & set that to `max-width:980px;` but for bigger devices make it `max-width:1180px;` then give the body background either a complimentary color or image with slight blur effect possibly. Once the screen size is less then 980px make the width 100%.

Comment: Thanks.
The problem with your solution is that it create a frame around the website.
I want it and every elements to be scaled.
I guess it has to be with viewport manipulation, but I haven't succeeded thus far to find the right way to do it.
I think Imma go with Vladimir M's comment for now,

Comment: That's why we use percentages, columns, rows etc. ie width is 980px, a row within this element is 100%, you may use 3 or 4 rows, within those rows you use columns which are (depending on margins) 50%-47% width & add padding. For three columns 33.33% each. Responsive design is based on position:relative, percentages, float:left, float:right, clear:both. You may need to look at Bootstrap or Foundation as a framework perhaps or at least to get an idea on how to apply a solution to making your website responsive.